# PCA on complex-valued data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pca

What's the correct way to undertake PCA on complex-valued data?

I see that [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/75733/pca-for-complex-valued-data?newreg=4b55d49db58e4f00beb716282ed0654d) solution exists.

Are there any python packages that have implemented a complex-PCA?

So far I have just broken my data into real and imaginary parts and performed PCA as if they were real. For example:

```
| sw  | fw | mw |
|4+4i |3+2i|1-1i|
```

would become:

```
| swreal | swimag | fwreal | fwimag | mwreal | mwimag |
|   4    |    4   |    3   |    2   |   1    |   -1   |
```

My PCA ends up looking like this:

[image]

**I want to pursue a complex PCA, but I'm not even sure how I would end up representing it? If it were a 2D plot, the only way is similar to above(?), in which case, would it look any different?**

Comment: I think Complex space is pretty isomorphic to Euclidean space, so algorithmically it shouldn't be a problem, but I don't know of any package. On plotting, one way I know of is to have a vertical axis representing the imaginary part, and horizontal one representing the real part, and both meeting at (0, 0i)

Comment: @user9370903 but then, if I were to plot with PC1 and PC2 as the axes, it would become a 3D plot. I don't think it would look 'different' to the plot above, with the imaginary and real components treated differently.